# SASS in Visual Studio: Keyframes and browser compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sass

I'm currently using SASS with Visual Studio (with Mindscape) and I want to create a simple mixin to don't have to write the -ms-, -o-, -webkit- etc...

I have this final CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animate-loading-bar {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: 50px 50px; }
}   

@-moz-keyframes animate-loading-bar {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: 50px 50px; }
}   

@-ms-keyframes animate-loading-bar {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: 50px 50px; }
}   

@keyframes animate-loading-bar {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: 50px 50px; }
}
```

So I try to create the mixin:

```
@mixin keyframe($name){
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$name} {
        0% { background-position: 0 0; }
        100% { background-position: 50px 50px; }
    }   

    @-ms-keyframes #{$name} {
        0% { background-position: 0 0; }
        100% { background-position: 50px 50px; }
    }   

    @-moz-keyframes #{$name} {
        0% { background-position: 0 0; }
        100% { background-position: 50px 50px; }
    }   

    @keyframes #{$name} {
        0% { background-position: 0 0; }
        100% { background-position: 50px 50px; }
    }   
}
```

But mindscape don't like the "@" in my mixin :(

How can I do that?

Thank